# F6 and F8 not working in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse Kepler. Shortcut keys like `F6` and `F8` are not working while debugging. I checked binding in `General->keys` but still they are not working.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If your keyboard has a `Fn` key, does it work when it's also pressed? Basically, do you have the function row set to act as multimedia and system controls rather than function keys?

Comment: How do I check if the function row is to to act as multimedia and system controls?

Comment: Yes my function keys are working for shortcuts other than in eclipse like in browser.

Comment: Which ones? Are you on a platform where those keys might be owned by something else? What happens if you change the bindings in Eclipse?

Comment: How do I check if those keys are owned by something else?